# LinearLayout: How to position elements

Tags: android, android-layout

I understand that I can use Relative layout when I want things relative to each other.
But if I use linear layout for simple positioning of elements, then I should be able to do that right?
My question is if I have textview and tablelayout inside linear layout (table and its title), how can I make title centered horizontally and the table centered veritically (assuming it takes the whole width of the screen)

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width = "fill_parent" android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
android:orientation= "veritical" >
    <TextView 
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content" android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity = "center_horizontal" />

    <tablelayout
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent" android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity = "center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But the above is not working (at the table is not being centered veritcall)
I want it to be like

```
***************TEXT VIEW**************
*
*
*
TABLE
*
*
*
```

What do you suggest???

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your TextView layout_height "fill_parent" and the your layout_gravity will work. Currently the textview is only as wide as the content. Same with the table, the layout_height would need to be fill_parent.

I would always recommend using relative layout where possible though.

Comment: HEllo, Thanks for the answer, but the layout_gravity should be able to move the whole widget right. I have fill parent for the lenear layout so I should be able to move the widget anywhere in this parent with the word layout_gravity

Comment: Your desciption would be correct if I am using android:gravity not android:layout_gravity

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not using ReleativeLayout?

Comment: Because I see lenear being the one that is the base and I want to learn the limitation so I know when to jump to relative layout.